# How to call javascript function from the form attribue value in hhtm?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          function sum() {
              i = 10;
              j = 10;
              result = i + j;
              return result;
           }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="sum()"><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to javascript, I am want to get number value in my input text box.Here I am doing sum of i and j and want there result directly show in the input box without using submit button.

Comment: why would you want that? please put a real example, maybe you need to change the design cause what you are doing, if you know the function serverside you can fill the value serverside which is safer to do (if the user has js disabled it will work anyway)

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. Value of the "value" attribute must be a literal and not function.
You need to set the value through javascript on page load:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector("input[name=fname]").value = sum();
};
```

Comment: can we acheieve it without javascript?

Comment: @user186730 No. Nevermind that `sum()` is already JavaScript. You'll need more of it than just the `function` declaration to do what you want as HTML alone can't call a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're feeling really wonky, you can replace your  tag with

```
<script>document.write('<input type="text" name="fname" value="'+sum()+'"/>');</script>
```